# Import tkinter as tk does not work with text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, import, text-widget

I tried to create a text widget with option `import tkinter as tk` but I don't know why the text methods not working with my object.
If I use `from tkinter import *` then it is all good, but as I read this is not the recommended importing method.
So, could you please advise why first code works and the second doesn't? What am I missing?

This works:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello.....")
text.insert(END, "Bye Bye.....")
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This doesn't:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello.....")
text.insert(END, "Bye Bye.....")
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks

Comment: Any time you are using anything from an import and you name that import rather than using * then you need to use the name you assigned to that import as a prefix for all methods/classes/constants you received from that import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

> **INSERT** is a *constant defined in Tkinter*, so you also need to precede it with Tkinter.

you need to use INSERT like:

```
tk.INSERT
```

your code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.insert(tk.INSERT, "Hello.....")
text.insert(tk.END, "Bye Bye.....")
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

in this case if you are using :

```
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello.....")
```

you will get an error:

> NameError: name 'INSERT' is not defined

Comment: I could not have figured that out for the sake of my life :(.
For me this does not make sense where to add this `tk.` for the below I tried all combination till finally got it working like this: `text.config(state=tk.DISABLED)`